# How to get document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height in node js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ejs, jsdom

I was try to get the height from html. I render the html using `ejs` because I need to insert a data into the html and then the result from ejs was processing with `jsdom` library.

I was write `<script>` in my html/ejs file to get the `document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height`. But the result is return 0. And when I try to run `document.body` its return `HTMLBodyElement {}`. I placed the `<script>` inside the `<body>`. I assume when the `document.body` was not return any value, then something mistake there.

here's my code :

```
await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      ejs.renderFile(path.join(__basedir, '/views/', 'pdf.ejs'), {
        title: fileNameGenerate,
        ...
      }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          console.error(err)
          reject(err);
          done(err)
        } else {
          const dom = new JSDOM(`${data}`, {runScripts: "dangerously"});

...
```

What's make the `document.body` not returning any value ?
PLease ask me if this informatiions is still not enough to solve that problem

Comment: With JSDOM you cant use `getBoundingClientRects`. From the [readme](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom): "there are two major features that are currently outside the scope of jsdom. These are: [...] Layout: the ability to calculate where elements will be visually laid out as a result of CSS, which impacts methods like `getBoundingClientRects()` or properties like `offsetTop`."

Comment: Ohh i see, but why the ```document.body``` is returning ```HTMLBodyElement {}``` ? . I was try to use ```document.body.scrollHeight``` if the ```getBoundingClientRects``` not possible